# .htaccess - subdomain not working with www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, plesk

I see a lot of questions about it here on SO, so I'm posting here:

I have a domain www.example.com and I have set .htaccess file to redirect all example.com to www.example.com

Now, I made (through my plesk 10 interface) a subdomain abc.example.com and what I would like is to also have www.abc.example.com so I entered (also in plesk) this:

```
www.abc.example.com.    CNAME   abc.example.com.
```

But it's not working. Do I need to reload/restart dns?(if so, please tell me how?) Or do I just need to wait certain time for this until it propagates?

Since my mentioned CNAME didn't work, I also added the .htaccess (which might be wrong (i know, not much of a server person :( )) in the abc folder which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abc.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

but with no luck, so please shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which worked for me in the end:

In Plesk I made one subdomain.domain.com pointing to lets say **abc** folder, and then I added the www.subdomain.domain.com also through Plesk but pointed it to the **same** abc folder. Then I added the .htaccess file inside this abc folder (where all other files for this subdomain reside) which now guarantees that all requests to subdomain.domain.com get redirected to www.subdomain.domain.com. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.subdomain.domain.com$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this will help someone beginning with this stuff like me.

Just to note, the credit for the idea of pointingthe www.subdomain inside the same folder goes to user Bryan White on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/266414/plesk-10-i-have-been-deleting-and-adding-subdomains-but-they-still-appear/266419#266419)

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abc\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abc\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abc.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However **DNS entry** for `abc.example.com` and `www.abc.example.com` might not have been propagated. You need to give it sometime (few hours may be) before you test this.

You can use **nslookup** on [Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525) or [*nix](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/unslooku.htm) to check when is your domain is available to the world.

Comment: strangely the dns for abc propagates instantly, wonder why is it so with www. hmm, i might be missing something here, cause your rewrite didn't help. New thing is that I'm getting plesk default page now, but :? i don't know from where is it pulling it from, as i don't see any folders marked as www.abc on my server :/

Comment: may be you added CNAME entry afterwards so it might take some time to propagate.

Comment: yes, but the fact is i don't know why is there a plesk default page showing up, and how to change this.

Comment: Do you have access to apache's access.log? Would give you best answer I believe.